# Configuring Kafka SSL with Let's Encrypt

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to setup a Kafka cluster and add SSL to it, but I'm getting always the same error:

```
INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Failed authentication with /XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

I read several stackoverflow posts about this problem but I cannot fix it.

I'm using Kafka 2.5.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 with OpenJDK 14 and I used Let's Encrypt to generate certificates for my domain name (that are working perfectly with nginx).

First I created a pkcs12 file with the following command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in fullchain.pem -inkey privkey.pem -out keystore.p12 -name kafka1 -CAfile chain.pem -caname root
```

...then I created the keystore (with the -ext option [as described in kafka docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_configcerthstname)):

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass 'STRONG_PASS' -destkeypass 'STRONG_PASS' -destkeystore keystore.jks -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass 'STRONG_PASS' -alias kafka1 -ext SAN=DNS:{FQDN}
```

...also I added the certificate to the truststore:

```
keytool -trustcacerts -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -importcert -file /etc/letsencrypt/live/YOURDOMAIN/chain.pem
```

At this point, I believe that I have all of the necessary steps to have the keystore and the truststore correctly configured.

My broker config is:

```
broker.id=0

listeners=SSL://mydomain.com:9092
ssl.keystore.location=/path/to/keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=password
ssl.key.password=password
ssl.truststore.location=/path/to/jdk/lib/security/cacerts
ssl.truststore.password=changeit
ssl.secure.random.implementation=SHA1PRNG
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm= # I tried with and without this and the problem persists

advertised.listeners=SSL://mydomain.com:9092
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/path/to/kafka_data

num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.num.partitions=3
offsets.topic.replication.factor=2
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
min.insync.replicas=2
default.replication.factor=2

log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=IP1:2181,IP2:2181,IP3:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000

group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=3000
```

Then I run the broker and try to execute the following command to know if everything is working:

```
openssl s_client -debug -connect mydomain.com:9092 -tls1 | head -n 50
```

And the error is displayed:

```
INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Failed authentication with /XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

My domain is not the same as my hostname in the machine, I don't know if it could be a problem. I only want to add security to the first broker and then repeat the same in the other two, but first have the first one working.

What is wrong with my config? Maybe the truststore? or the hostname and domain name?

Comment: PKCS12 is the default keystore format since Java 9 (no longer JKS), maybe it's not what you expect: https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/jdk9-keytool-transitions-default-keystore-to-pkcs12

Comment: But I'm using PKCS12 keystore format, what do you mean?

Comment: You use keytool without specifying the destination store type with -deststoretype, it uses PKCS12 but I see '-destkeystore keystore.jks' in your code, it's a bit misleading, I thought you needed a JKS keystore. Kafka uses JKS as a store type by default: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_ssl.keystore.type